# Use the PI to mirror a screen from machine to display, over ethernet

Tags: pi-3

I want to use my PI to show the display of a machine which runs Linux on a second display which is located somewhere else in a factory. The PI will be located next to this display and connected via HDMI and via Ethernet to the machine.
We have used a VGA splitter on the machine and put a cable to the other place in the building were we want to see the display of the machine, but this isn't working well due to interference.
On Windows I can install UltraVNC and connect to the machine to show the actual display of the machine.
How can I accomplish this with my PI, I looked around for questions but most of them deal with connecting remotely to a PI, but thats not what I need.

Ideally the PI should operate without any user interference, it only needs to connect to the machine and mirror the screen via its HDMI output. 
Is there any software that can be used for this?
If possible the software should automatically reconnect when the machine is started at the beginning of the day and mirror the screen without user interference.

Comment: VNC runs on the Pi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this by running a VNC Viewer on the Pi and a VNC server on the other Linux machine.

The RealVNC Viewer which comes installed with Raspbian has a feature whereby it will automatically reconnect if disconnected, which you may find useful.

Assuming you're using the RealVNC server on the other Linux machine, you'll probably want to set the IdleTimeout parameter (under VNC Options > Expert) to 0, since the default is to close the connection if there has been no input from the viewer for 1 hour.